# conditionally rendered columns Cognos

Tags: cognos

I have a report that I developed that utilizes render variables as described here - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/cognos/reporting/dynamic_report_design/page570.html

The report for some reason still renders the column header without the data below when its exported to Excel. If I view in HTML, it renders appropriately but the HTML includes every single column header.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check "Making the Query Items Dynamic" #4 from that document. Looks like you miss it

Comment: Sorry.. let me clarify. The report behaves correctly when viewed in HTML, but not when exported.

Answer (score 0):

When you are applying the **Render Variable**, make sure you are selecting the 'List Column' **not** the 'List Column Body'. Look into the attached screenshot to see how to select the complete **List Column** when applying the Render Variable.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this technique wouldn't work when exported but as a workaround, you could try applying the render variable independently to the column and its header.